# Does Blender 2.82 allow for Radeon VII GPU rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a Radeon VII GPU but it doesn't show up in Blender. I am on Ubuntu 18.04. I have opencl installed so I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Did you enable it in the Preferences?

Comment: Yes, when I go to preferences OpenCL it says there are no compatible GPUs